# Logical implications in classic logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following problem:

> If Joseph is playing piano or Joaquim is playing guitar, then John is
>   not sleeping.

I perfectly understood the situation but didn't understand the **second row of the truth table**. For me if p and q are true then r is true  (This is the same as what's on the first line), but there it's false. Can someone explain?

[image]

****UPDATE**: From what I understood, it was placed all the possibilities. Why that? If p is true and q is true then r false **is NOT a possibility**.

Comment: Perhaps you think $r$ means he is not asleep, in fact $r$ here is he is sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p:=$ he is playing piano
$1:=$ he is playing guitar
$r:=$ he is asleep

So the second raw means in the situation that ($p$) he is playing piano, ($q$) he is playing guitar and 
($\lnot r)$ he is not asleep, then the given proposition of the problem is valid.

Comment: Then the first line is invalid?

Comment: Yes, because in that situation he is playing piano and guitar, but $r$ is  true. it means he is asleep.